# Printing strings for linked list

Tags: c, string, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I've been trying out linked lists for our Data Structure class, But I am still confused on how to implement linked list with strings. Other sources told me to use strcpy() for scanning, other sources told me to use "%[^\n]%*c", but nothing works out for me.

I made a simple code for linked list strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TWENTY 20

struct Node {
    char data[TWENTY];
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head = NULL;

void printList(struct Node* n);

int main() {
    struct Node name;

    printf_s("Input Char: ");
    scanf_s("%[^\n]%*c", name.data);

    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = name.data;
    head->next = NULL; 

    printList(head);

    return 0;
}

void printList(struct Node* n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        printf(" %c ", n->data);
        //n = n->next;
    }
}
```

The code gives out an error of:

```
array type 'char[20]' is not assignable.
```

Comment: You use `strcpy()` for copying strings, not for scanning.

Answer (score 1):

When interacting with strings in C, use the [functions in `string.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring) to manipulate them.

A C string is an array of characters terminated by a `'\0'`.

When you try to:

```
head->data = name.data;
```

This doesn't work. because `data` is an array and you can't assign to an array this way. As you're working with strings, you should use `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(head->data, name.data);
```

However, because `data` is an array of 20 characters (which allows for a string 19 characters long), you should use [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) to ensure you don't experience buffer overflows.